# MQT automatic `set integrity off` when underlying table updated

Tags: db2, materialized-view

Have a slow query. Need an MQT so the optimizer will rewrite the query and use my MQT instead.

Problem: a manual full refresh is much much faster than using `refresh immediate` type or a staging table: because of the structure of our db updating a single row takes 6 minutes! Just refreshing the MQT takes 30s.

So I chose the `refresh deferred` type, but db2 has no such thing as automatic MQT invalidation, when underlying tables change! I tried updating the table, but my MQT remains accessible.

What to do? Create a trigger on each table, which calls `set integrity off`?

current DDL:

```
create table xfacetattr as (
  SELECT
    distinct
  -- filter columns:
    AVD.language_id,
    A.storeent_id A_storeent_id,
    ADSC.mastercatalog_id
    ,
  -- return columns:
    ADSC.SRCHFIELDNAME,
    AVD.value,
    AV.storeent_id,
    AVD.sequence,
    AVD.image1,
    AVD.image2
  FROM
    attrdictsrchconf ADSC,
    attr A,
    attrval AV,
    attrvaldesc AVD
  WHERE
    ADSC.ATTR_ID           IS NOT NULL
  AND ADSC.attr_id          = A.attr_id
  AND A.facetable           = 1
  AND AV.attr_id            = A.attr_id
  AND AV.attrval_id         = AVD.attrval_id
  --and 1=2
) data initially deferred refresh deferred
;


create trigger xfacetattr_t1 after update of attr_id,facetable, storeent_id on attr FOR EACH STATEMENT call XEXECUTE('set integrity for xfacetattr off');
create trigger xfacetattr_t2 after insert on attr FOR EACH STATEMENT call XEXECUTE('set integrity for xfacetattr off');
create trigger xfacetattr_t3 after delete on attr FOR EACH STATEMENT call XEXECUTE('set integrity for xfacetattr off');

create trigger xfacetattr_t4 after update of mastercatalog_id,SRCHFIELDNAME,ATTR_ID on attrdictsrchconf FOR EACH STATEMENT call XEXECUTE('set integrity for xfacetattr off');
create trigger xfacetattr_t5 after insert on attrdictsrchconf FOR EACH STATEMENT call XEXECUTE('set integrity for xfacetattr off');
create trigger xfacetattr_t6 after delete on attrdictsrchconf FOR EACH STATEMENT call XEXECUTE('set integrity for xfacetattr off');

create trigger xfacetattr_t7 after update of storeent_id,attr_id,attrval_id on attrval FOR EACH STATEMENT call XEXECUTE('set integrity for xfacetattr off');
create trigger xfacetattr_t8 after insert on attrval FOR EACH STATEMENT call XEXECUTE('set integrity for xfacetattr off');
create trigger xfacetattr_t9 after delete on attrval FOR EACH STATEMENT call XEXECUTE('set integrity for xfacetattr off');

create trigger xfacetattr_t10 after update of language_id,value,sequence,image1,image2,attrval_id on attrvaldesc FOR EACH STATEMENT call XEXECUTE('set integrity for xfacetattr off');
create trigger xfacetattr_t11 after insert on attrvaldesc FOR EACH STATEMENT call XEXECUTE('set integrity for xfacetattr off');
create trigger xfacetattr_t12 after delete on attrvaldesc FOR EACH STATEMENT call XEXECUTE('set integrity for xfacetattr off');
```

Comment: I'm not sure how issuing `set integrity off` on the MQT solves your problem.

Comment: @mustaccio doing this ensures query result always consistent, just slower sometimes, because MQT not used by optimizer. I can poll SYSCAT.TABLES.ACCESS_MODE and issue `set integrity for xfacetattr immediate checked` when it's not 'F'

Comment: "Automatic MQT invalidation" is implemented by setting the value of `CURRENT REFRESH AGE` in the session, which will prevent the optimizer from using the MQT beyond the refresh age threshold.

Comment: @mustaccio `REFRESH AGE` register name is irrelevant to what it really does

Comment: It has only 2 positions: off (0) and on (99999999999999). When switched on, query rewrite is allowed.

Comment: I guess I don't understand what you want to achieve then. Do you want to prevent the optimizer from using the MQT? Do you query the MQT directly? May be you could edit the question to clarify?

Comment: @mustaccio MQT will be consistend most of the time and optimizer will use it. When I do a **rare** table update, MQT should become unusable by optimizer. If I see that MQT has `ACCESS_MODE = 'N'` I will refresh it manually.

Comment: It sounds to me like you've decided on a solution (an MQT) without really considering the problem (slow query performance).  Have you determined *why* your query is slow and how you can *really* fix it ?  Why does it take "6 minutes" to update a single row?

Comment: @IanBjorhovde it's IBM Websphere Commerce, better not change existing tables. There's a relation 1:1000000. This is why it takes 6 minutes to update.